# Fabric plug-in for Android Studio keeps logging me out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, google-fabric, android-studio-plugin

I stumbled upon an issue with the Fabric plug-in for Android Studio. Basically, the plug-in keeps logging me out every other screen change. I tried updating AS to the latest stable version (3.1.3) and disabling/reenabling uninstalling/reinstalling the Fabric plug-in, but the issue is still there.

Visiting [the plug-in page on JetBrains site](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8002-fabric-for-android-studio), I noticed a user was having the same issue, like, eight months ago. [That user wrote](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8002-fabric-for-android-studio#comment=24723):

> I consistently get a login loop. Using valid credentials I get no error message. I get to the next page right before getting bumped back to login. This prevents manual uploads and is super frustrating.

Unfortunately, there is also no way to distribute a build using Fabric's web site.

Therefore, my question is: Has anyone found a solution to the Android Studio plug-in issue? How would be possible to circumvent the issue and keep distributing builds using that plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the login loop in Android Studio by logging into the fabric website via a browser and accepting a new terms agreement

Comment: It started working again "on its own", and in the meantime I had indeed to log in to the website and possibly accept whatever new terms agreement was brought in (thanks to GDPR, I presume). Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a guide to distribute builds using Gradle](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html), where the given command line example can be generalized as

```
gradlew assemble<BuildVariant> crashlyticsUploadDistribution<BuildVariant>
```

to select one from multiple flavors or build types that your project may have. Specifically, a `<BuildVariant>` is composed by `<Flavor><BuildType>`, properly camel-cased.

I would have liked to avoid this route, and doing stuff from the comfort of the plug-in window, but it works, and that's what matters in the end.